# How to build html5lib parser to deal with a mixture of XML and HTML tags?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse an HTML file consists of many individual documents downloaded as a batch from LexisNexis (legal database).

- My first task is to split the HTML file into its constituent documents. I thought this would be easy since the documents are surrounded by     `<DOC NUMBER=1>body of the 1st document</DOC>`  and so on.
- However, this `<DOC>` tag is an XML tag, not an HTML tag (all other tags in the file are HTML). Due to this, with the regular HTML parser, this tag is not available in the tree.
- How can I build a parser in bs4 that will pick up this XML tag?
  I enclose the relevant section of the HTML file:

  `<!-- Hide XML section from browser <DOC NUMBER=1> <DOCFULL> --> BODY <!-- Hide XML section from browser </DOCFULL> </DOC> -->`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify xml in bs4 when your BeautifulSoup object is instantiated:

```
xml_soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_object, 'xml')
```

This should take care of your issue. You *can* use the `xml_soup` object to parse the remaining html, however I'd recommend instantiating another soup object specifically for html:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_object)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I tried that, but I think it doesn't process it properly. If I try xml_soup("doc"), nothing is returned and if I try print(xml_soup.prettify), I get a long line of  File"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1021, in decode
    indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1068, in decode_contents  
Finally interrupted by: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: That recursion error shouldn't happen. It is probably a bug in bs4 If you're up to using BeautifulSoup3, instead of doing `xml_soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_object, 'xml')`, you can use bs3's BeautifulStoneSoup. After installing bs3, do: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup` then `xml_soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_object)`